# How to unload a child user Control that is Loaded on parent control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I Am working with user controls in Asp.net.

I am loading a user Control(Usercontro2) in a Control panel of  a parent child control (Usercontro1).

Now I want to unload the control on the click of  link button of Usercontro2

How can I do it in the Child user control.

Answer (score 0):

You should do nothing in this case.  Once the button is clicked, the postback is sent to the server.  If you do not create the UserControl again in this request, it won't appear in the client after the page is posted back.